# How to toggle IME Display input method at center of screen

Tags: windows-10, ime

If IME (Input Method Editor) is installed, by default the input method is displayed at center of screen for 1 sec when switching input methods. How to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

```
Settings (Win-I)
 -> Time & Languages
  -> Japanese (or any language supporting IME)
   -> Options
    -> Microsoft IME
     -> Options
      -> Appearance
       -> Display input method at center of screen: On/Off
```